# How to overwrite output files in SQLcl Liquibase?

Tags: oracle-apex, liquibase, sqlcl

I am learning Liquibase, exporting Oracle Apex application like this:

```
PS D:\projects\RDNA2\db\rdna2-apex> sql rdna2@rdna2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8


SQLcl: Release 23.2 Production on Fri Sep 22 10:50:12 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2023, Oracle.  All rights reserved.   

Password? (**********?) ******
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.20.0.0.0

SQL> lb generate-apex-object -applicationid 200 -split
```

It generates files just fine. But next time I do this it make new files. I found `--overwrite-output-file` parameter for Liquibase, but it doesn't work in SQLcl version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support that option, you'll need to start with an empty directory.

We have that request logged as an enhancement, and I don't see why we couldn't enable that behavior.

Comment: Wait, maybe I am stupid and don't understand typical workflow with Liquibase. What I do:
- Make some changes in Apex.
- Delete all from scripts folder.
- Export all.
- Commit to git.
- Have main.xml where listed 3 changelogs, for schema objects, Apex workspace and Apex application.
- Update other server using main.xml.
- Never change main.xml.
Am I right or should I use it differently?

Comment: I have started with an empty directory. In every generate-apex-object command, instead of updating the same GIT files, it creates separate folders. Could you please help with the same?

Comment: Read my answer, it's an enhancement request, not currently supported

Comment: Thank you for the information @thatjeffsmith.  Could you please share the the probable timeline you will be delivering the same? Or for a huge project, I need to always delete the existing folder and generate all again.